# Prove that if remainder of improper integral converges,then given improper integral also converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

If for some $A$, $\int_A^\infty f(x)dx$ is convergent then $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ ($a<A$) is also convergent and $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx=\int_a^A f(x)dx + \int_A^\infty f(x)dx$

We know that $\int_a^B f(x)dx=\int_a ^Af(x) + \int_A^Bf(x)dx$

Because $f(x)$ is integrable on $[c,d]$ $\int_a ^Af(x)dx$ is finite.We have $\int_A^\infty f(x)dx$ is convergent so if we take limit as $B\to +\infty$ we get

$\int_a^\infty f(x)dx=\int_a^Af(x)+\int_A^\infty f(x)dx$.What I did is correct?Sorry if this seems silly question improper integrals are new chapter for me.

EDIT.

In order $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ to be convergent $\iff$ for some $A$ $\int_A ^\infty f(x)dx$ to be convergent.

Comment: Your statement that if $\int_A^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges then $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx$ also converges for any $a<A$ is incorrect. For instance $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ with $A=1$ and $a=0$.

Comment: @Snaw Edited question.

Comment: @Snaw Also in my book we defined improper integrals on $[a,+\infty]$ s.t. $f$ is integrable on any $[a,A]$ segment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a few details that I believe you assume but don't really state. Suppose

$$\int_b^\infty f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$$

converges, and that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ for some $a<b$ (this is the part you need that you were not very clear about). Then you have that

\begin{align*}
\int_a^\infty f(x)~\mathrm{d}x&=\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_a^c f(x)~\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\lim_{c\to\infty}\left(\int_a^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\int_b^c f(x)~\mathrm{d}x\right) \\
&=\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_a^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_b^c f(x)~\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_a^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x+\int_b^\infty f(x)~\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

and so since the right-hand side clearly exists, so does the left-hand side, and thus

$$\int_a^\infty f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$$

converges.

Comment: If we didn't know that $\int_b^c f(x)dx$ is convergent could you  write limit as sum of limits?

Comment: No, we need to have that it converges to justify splitting the limit up, so this entire proof requires that the integral converges to begin with.

Comment: Yep that's what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Character's Invarariance Theorem for Improper Integrals:**

Let $f\,\in\,\mathcal{C}[a,b)$ with $a\,\in\,\mathbb{R}\,\text{and}\, b\, \in \, \bar{\mathbb{R}}$.

Then, $\forall c\,\in\, (a,b)$, the character of $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ is the same as $\int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx$. Also:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx+\int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx$$

***Proof:***

We are going to change the improper integral to a proper integral, using limits:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{M\to b}\int_{a}^{M}f(x)dx$$
And:
$$\int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{M\to b}\int_{b}^{M}f(x)dx$$

So, by the linearity of definite integrals:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{M\to b}\int_{a}^{M}f(x)dx=\underbrace{\int_{a}^{c}f(x)}_\text{Proper I. $\implies$ Convergent}dx+\lim_{M\to b}\int_{b}^{M}f(x)dx$$

From here, it follows the thesis.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thank you too!..

Comment: @unit1991: if this answer has been useful, let me know smashing that +1 button and acceptred answer. Thanks.